# Javascript Update text from array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update a text on a click event, but somehow the index of the foreach always give me the first iteration 0, what am I missing:

```
var sliderTitles = document.getElementsByClassName('avia-caption-title');
var nextSlideBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('next-slide');
var prevSlideBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('prev-slide');

for (var i=0; i < nextSlideBtns.length; i++) {
    nextSlideBtns.item(i).onclick = setBtnNames();
}

setBtnNames();

function setBtnNames() {
    console.log("clickedd");
    Array.from(nextSlideBtns).forEach(
        function(element, index, array) {
            console.log(index); // always returns 0
            if(index == 5) {
                element.innerHTML = sliderTitles[0].innerHTML;
            } else {
                element.innerHTML = sliderTitles[index+1].innerHTML;    
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Should be `nextSlideBtns.item(i).onclick = setBtnNames;` — the `()` causes the function to be *called* and the return value used.

Comment: Please add some HTML, so we can recreate your issue

Comment: are you able to provide more code here (eg the html) and maybe a link to a codepen / fiddle etc?

Comment: Also if your code is in a `<script>` block at the top of your HTML, the DOM queries will return empty lists because the DOM will not yet have been fully parsed.

Comment: when I try in a snippet with @Pointy's correction and some empty buttons as HTML, it works all right. Are your slides dynamically created on the fly maybe? Or always the same slide HTML element that is updated?

Comment: @Kaddath they are created onload

Comment: @Pointy tried both some result

Comment: @Pointy the code is after the closing body tag

Comment: In that case, maybe slides are separate but the buttons are always the same? that's why adding HTML to the question would be really useful (note, your code should be executed in onload too then)

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in a fiddle / codepen / snippet ?